# how can I replace the value with the key in dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I want the function inverse to return this output:

```
{3: ['I', 'love'], 2: ['python']}
```

the function will replace the key and the value, but if there's the same value twice, it'll be one key. how can I do that?
// here's the code:

```
def inverse(dict1):

   def main():
        dict1 = {'I': 3, 'love': 3, 'python': 2}
        print(inverse(dict1))

    if __name__ == "__main__": 
        main()
```

Comment: Any attempt from you?

Comment: I really have no idea how can I do that. I'm not sure how to replace value and key without knowing exactly what they are.

Comment: [Here you go: a description of python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

```
dict1={'I': 3, 'love': 3, 'python': 2}
res_dict={}
for key,val in dict1.items():
    if res_dict.has_key(val):
        res_dict[val].append(key)
    else:
        res_dict[val]=[key]
```